# Why is a sidebar configured to run with an onOpen function not appearing when making a copy of the original spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am sharing a spreadsheet/app intended to be used as an evaluation tool for some coworkers. I want them to make a copy of the original spreadsheet (template) and work on their own so they don't overlap while submitting answers.

First I configured an alert and it worked perfectly. When making a copy it popped up again when the copy opened. Then I configured a sidebar and this isn't working. They are both running on the same onOpen function and the main difference between them is that the sidebar has HTML.

**This is the .gs code:**

```
//Displays spreadsheet use instructions.
fu
nction showInstructions() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('¡Recuerda leer las instrucciones de uso antes de comenzar!');
}

//Displays thanks banner after submitting form.
function showThanks() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('¡Gracias por participar!');
}

//Pops instructions and creates menus.
function onOpen() {   

  showInstructions();
  showSidebar();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuButtons = [ {name: "Submit", functionName: "submit"}];
  ss.addMenu("BIMmx", menuButtons);
}

function submit() {
  askName();
  copyData();
  showThanks();
  clear();
}

//Show sidebar with instructions.
function showSidebar() {
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar').setTitle('Instrucciones');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(output);
}

//Asks for user name before submitting data to master sheet.
function askName() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  //Display prompt.
  var result; 
  var text = "";

  while (text == ""){
    result = ui.prompt(
      '¡Completa la evaluación!',
      'Ingresa tu nombre:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

    // Process user's response.
    var button = result.getSelectedButton();
    text = result.getResponseText();
    if (text == "") 
      ui.alert('Nombre no puede estar vacío.');
    else if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
      // User clicked "OK".
      ui.alert('Tu nombre es ' + text + '.');
    } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
      // User clicked "Cancel".
      ui.alert('No entendí eso.');
    } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
      // User clicked X in the title bar.
      ui.alert('Cerraste el diálogo.');
    }


  }

 fillUser(text);

}

//Fills rows with submitting username.
function fillUser(result) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("K2").setValue(result);  
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var lc = ss.getLastColumn();
  var fillDownRange = ss.getRange(2, lc, lr-1);
  ss.getRange("K2").copyTo(fillDownRange);
}

//Backup data to master spreadsheet.  
function copyData() {

  var sss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sss.getSheetByName('Input');  
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,11);
  var sData=rg.getValues().join(";");

  //Cambiar por dirección del nuevo servicio web
  var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbywmtl7mpwd0RO2bS-bvFuYFlo-7Nv3zPTvphwjIDa0GwERTV8/exec";  

  var payload = {    
    "sData" : JSON.stringify(sData),    
  }

  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "payload" : payload,
    "followRedirects" : true,
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
  };

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  //Logger.log(JSON.parse(result));  


}

//Clean sheet once submission is done.  
function clear() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Input');
  sheet.getRange('A2:K').clearContent();
}
```

**This is the .html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe width="300" height="168.75" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T2pCuKOoo3I" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <p>
     - Haz una copia del documento marcado como (Template) y trabaja sobre ella.
    </p>
    <p>
    1. Renombra la copia que creaste como “RecursosHumanos-EvaluadorDeDesempeno-TuNombre.
    </p>
    <p>
    2. Lee los comentarios de cada rubro a evaluar desplazando el cursor/mouse por su encabezado.
    </p>
    <p>
    3. Evalúa a tus colegas.
    </p>
    <p>
    4. Incluye tu nombre y usa tu fila como auto-evaluación.
    </p>
    <p>
    5. Ingresa los datos en el menú BIMmx > Submit.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to make the sidebar pop-up as well when making a copy? Thanks for the help!

Comment: sidebars need authorization before they can run, your case "Display and run third-party web content in prompts and sidebars inside Google applications" So making a copy will not allow the sidebar to open until it is authorized.

Comment: While @utphx is right, there is a workaround for this, you can create a custom menu option ([instructions here](https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2016/05/02/add-custom-menus-google-docs-sheets-forms/)) to open the side-bar. Permissions with triggers, even with installable ones, can be slightly limited for security reasons.

Comment: Ok, so @amolina, open the sidebar from a menu instead of automatically popping when opening the spreadsheet?

Comment: Exactly, using the instructions I put in my previous comment, you can add the function that creates the sidebar to a menu. The best part is that you can set the menu entirely through the UI, you don't need to change the code (I'd suggest changing the name from `onOpen` though)